# Axes position and axes label in RevolutionPlot

Tags: plotting, style

Consider Revolution plot:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[t^4 - 1.2 t^2, {t, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["Re \[Phi]", Bold, 22], 
   Style["Im \[Phi]", Bold, 22], Style["V(\[Phi])", Bold, 22]}, 
 Ticks -> {{-6, 6}, {-10, 10}}]
```

It produces a picture on the left. I want it to produce the picture on the right. Could you please tell me how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Does using the options `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, -0.3},
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]` get you close enough to what you want?

Comment: @JasonB.:thank you! Only the arrows are absent.

Comment: if you think I closed this question in error, let me know